# How is line buffering implemented for C stdio input streams?

Tags: unix, stdio, buffering

I understand that fully buffered input can be implemented by issuing a single `read` syscall for a block of data possibly larger than required by the application. But I don't understand how line buffering could ever be applied to input without support from the kernel. I imagine one would have to read a block of data and then look for newlines, but if so, what is the difference with full buffering?

---

To be more specific:

Suppose I have an input stream `FILE* in`. Is there any difference between the following, with regards to how the `stdio` library will retrieve bytes from the operating system to fill its buffer?

- Line buffering: `setvbuf(in, NULL, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ)`
- Full buffering: `setvbuf(in, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ)`

If so, what is that difference?

Comment: Simply, the input data is not sent to application until LF or EOF is found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `FILE` struct has a default internal buffer.  After `fopen`, and on an `fread`, `fgets`, etc., the buffer is populated by the stdio layer from a `read(2)` call.

When you do `fgets`, it will copy data to *your* buffer, pulling it from the internal buffer [until newline is found].  If no newline is found, the stream internal buffer is replenished with another `read(2)` call.  Then, the scan for newline and fill of your buffer continues.

This can repeat a number of times [particularly true if you're doing `fread`]. Whatever is left over is available for the next stream read operation (e.g. `fread`, `fgets`, `fgetc`).

You can set the size of stream buffer with `setlinebuf`.  For efficiency, the typical default size is the machine page size [IIRC].

So, the stream buffer "stays one step ahead of you", so to speak.  It operates much like a ring queue [in effect, if not actuality].

---

Dunno for sure, but line buffering [or *any* buffering *mode*] is usually for output files (e.g. set for stdout by default).  It says, if you see a newline, do an implied `fflush`. Full buffering means do the `fflush` when the buffer is full.  Unbuffered means do `fflush` on *every* character.

If you open an output logfile, you get full buffering [most efficient], so if your program crashes, you might not get the last N lines output (i.e. they're still pending in the buffer). You *can* set line buffering so you get the last trace line after a program crash.

On input, line buffering doesn't have any meaning for a file [AFAICT].  It just tries to use the most efficient size possible (e.g. the stream buffer size).

I think that the important point is that, on input, you don't know where the newline is *beforehand*, so `_IOLBF` operates like any other mode--because it *has* to. (i.e.) you do read(2) up to stream buf size (or the amount needed to fulfill the outstanding `fread`). In other words, the only things that matter are the internal buffer size and the size/count parameters of the `fread` and *not* the buffering mode.

---

For TTY device (e.g. stdin), the stream will wait for newline [unless you use a TIOC* ioctl on the underlying fildes (e.g. 0) to set char-at-a-time aka raw mode], *regardless* of the stream mode.  That's because the TTY device canonical processing layer [in the kernel] will hold up the read (e.g. that's why you can type backspace, etc. without the application having to deal with it).

However, doing `fgets` on a TTY device/stream will get special treatment internally (e.g.) it will do select/poll and get the number of pending chars and read only that amount, so it won't block on the read. It will then look for newline, and reissue select/poll if no newline found.  But, if newline found, it returns from the `fgets`.  In other words, it will do whatever is necessary to allow the expected behavior on stdin.  It wouldn't do for it to block on a 4096 byte read if the user entered 10 chars + newline.

---

**UPDATE:**

To answer your second round of followup questions

> I see the tty subsystem and the stdio code running in the process as completely independent. The only way they interface is by the process issuing read syscalls; these may block or not, and this is what depends on the tty settings.

Normally, that is true.  Most applications do *not* try to adjust the TTY layer settings. But, an app *can* do so if it wishes to, but *not* via any stream/stdio functions.

> But the process is completely unaware of those settings and can't change them.

Again, normally true.  But, again, the process *can* change them.

> If we're on the same page, what you're saying implies that a setvbuf call will change the buffering policy of the tty device, and I find that hard to reconcile with my understanding of Unix I/O.

**No** `setvbuf` only sets the *stream* buffer size and policy. It has nothing to do with the kernel at all. The kernel only sees `read(2)` and has *no* idea whether the app did it raw or whether the stream did it via `fread` [or `fgets`]. It does *not* affect the TTY layer in any way.

In a normal app that is looping on `fgetc` and a user inputs `abcdef\n`, the `fgetc` will block [in the driver] *until* the newline is entered.  This is the TTY canonical processing layer doing this. Then, when the newline is entered, the `read(2)` done by the `fgetc` will return with the value of `7`. the first `fgetc` will return and the remaining six will occur rapidly, being fulfilled from the *stream's* internal buffer.

> **However ...**

More sophisticated apps may change the TTY layer policy via `ioctl(fileno(stdin),TIOC*,...)`. The stream will *not* be aware of this. So when doing so, one must be careful. Thus, if a process wants, it can fully control the TTY layer behind the file unit, but must do manually via the `ioctl`

Using the `ioctl` to modify [or even disable] TTY canonical processing [aka "TTY raw mode"] can be used by applications that need true char-at-a-time input.  For example, `vim`, `emacs`, `getkey`, etc.

While an application *can* intermix raw mode and a `stdio` stream [and do so effectively], the normal usage is to either use streams in their normal mode/usage **or** *bypass* the stdio layer entirely, do `ioctl(0,TIOC*,...)` and then do `read(2)` *directly*.

---

Here's a sample `getkey` program:

```
// getkey -- wait for user input

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    int remain;
    int err;
    int oflag;
    int stdflg;
    char *cp;
    struct termios tiold;
    struct termios tinew;
    int len;
    int flag;
    char buf[1];
    int code;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    stdflg = 0;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 's':
            stdflg = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("using %s\n",stdflg ? "fgetc" : "read");

    fd = fileno(stdin);

    oflag = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,oflag | O_NONBLOCK);

    err = tcgetattr(fd,&tiold);
    if (err < 0)
        sysfault("getkey: tcgetattr failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));

    tinew = tiold;

#if 1
    tinew.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP |
        INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tinew.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tinew.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tinew.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    tinew.c_cflag |= CS8;

#else
    cfmakeraw(&tinew);
#endif

#if 0
    tinew.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tinew.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
#endif

    err = tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,&tinew);
    if (err < 0)
        sysfault("getkey: tcsetattr failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));

    for (remain = 9;  remain > 0;  --remain) {
        printf("\rHit any key within %d seconds to abort ...",remain);
        fflush(stdout);

        sleep(1);

        if (stdflg) {
            len = fgetc(stdin);
            if (len != EOF)
                break;
        }
        else {
            len = read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));
            if (len > 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,&tiold);
    fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,oflag);

    code = (remain > 0);

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s (%d remaining) ...\n",code ? "abort" : "normal",remain);

    return code;
}
```

Comment: Right, I understand this much. The question is about what goes on at this point: "the buffer is populated by the stdio layer". As I understand it, if and how this is done depends on the type of buffering of the stream. Is there any difference between full and line buffering, with regards to how the stdio library populates its internal buffer (via calls to `read(2)`)?
Of course what happens with a call to `fgets` is a completely different thing and it's not what I meant to ask about.

Comment: "on input, you don't know where the newline is beforehand"
Exactly, this is what motivated my question. So there doesn't seem to be any difference. I wonder why the distinction even exists... Maybe it's in case a kernel implements special support for `read(2)`ing one line at a time.

Comment: No, it is the tty subsystem that make data available from different criterions. Craig said it: tty device processing makes the difference.

Comment: I'm confused. I see the tty subsystem and the stdio code running in the process as completely independent. The only way they interface is by the process issuing `read` syscalls; these may block or not, and this is what depends on the tty settings. But the process is completely unaware of those settings and can't change them. If we're on the same page, what you're saying implies that a `setvbuf` call will change the buffering policy of the tty device, and I find that hard to reconcile with my understanding of Unix I/O.

Comment: No. `setvbuf` is for output and as nothing to do with tty; more on this `setvbuf` is for stdio, but `read` is not stdio, it is a system call. With stdio you add another buffering, user space buffering. We are talking about system space buffering. Ttys are at system level.

Comment: +1 for it's really worth mentioning that a `FILE` object (a stream)'s internally buffer is completely different from a `fgets` required buffer parameter. This just confused me for hours before I wrote some code to figure it out.

Comment: Minor nit: the function that sets the size of a stream buffer is `setvbuf()` or its convenience wrapper `setbuffer()`. I couldn't find a `setlinebuffer` function anywhere. There is a convenience wrapper named `setlinebuf()`, but that only switches a stream to line-buffered mode.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Thanks. `setlinebuffer` was a typo for `setlinebuf`--fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about line discipline for terminal input. Terminals, at least on Unix systems, are special kernel subsystems that provide connection in between a character provider, and the kernel. Line buffering, full buffering or raw inputs refers to the way characters are delivered to the kernel and available to user processes. So, processes don't make any difference in between reading a tty or a file; it's only the subsystem that makes a semantic difference on what is available to I/O subsystem. You may read [TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) to start understanding what happens with TTY I/Os.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very interesting. I don't think line discipline for terminal input is relevant to the question, though, as it concerns the "write" side of the pipe/stream. As you say, the reading process (in particular the `stdio` library it uses) doesn't make a difference between reading a tty or a file, except for the default buffering mode which can be changed later anyway.

Comment: No you are wrong! It concerns the input side, user inputs are subject to the line discipline (this is what permits input line editing!). When your process reads something from stdin, it can read what is only available from the tty subsystem which delivers the data with different discipline. There is no such a construct while output occurs. For output, stdio buffers with some discipline but the data is delivered to the tty as is. There is a kind of symmetry...

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no difference between line and full buffering as far as STDIN is concerned, because libc would still need to read a larger block to find newlines in it. There is no support to read individual lines from kernel pipe buffers. Consider the following example:

```
printf "a\nb\nc\n" | (sed 1q ; sed 1q ; sed 1q)
a
```

As you can see, the first `sed` instance took all the data, while trying to read a single line. The result will be the same regardless of whether STDIN is fully buffered or line buffered. For example, check [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) man page:

> If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered. This option is invalid with standard input.

The difference between full and line buffering becomes visible in output streams, controlling when they are flushed.

Comment: I've edited the title to make clear that this question is about C's stdio library, which has no `read` function. I'm asking about the implementation of the buffering scheme, not its behaviour.

Comment: I've changed my answer, see if it fits better now.